# Nginx reverse proxy holding open all connections just over 1 second?

Tags: nginx

My config:

```
upstream api-backend {
        server localhost:9005;
}

server {
        listen 80;

        lingering_close off;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html;

        location /api/ {
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT';
                proxy_pass      http://api-backend/;
        }

        location / {
                expires off;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

I'm serving up files out of /var/www/html and the /api endpoint forwards to a Go service. The Go service finishes requests in a few ms but Chrome's network tab reports the requests are all taking a few ms longer than 1s.

I believe it's Nginx that's keeping the connection open. How can I figure out what's keeping the connection alive and how to close it as fast as possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably start with [keepalive_disable](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#keepalive_disable), which can go at http, server, or location level. However, the default is 75s, so this may not solve the problem.

Is this keepalive preventing the client receiving the data? Can you post a screenshot of your Chrome network tab and describe the problem you're seeing?

Keepalives are [generally a good thing](https://www.nginx.com/blog/tuning-nginx/). They prevent overhead of having to establish a connection again if data is requested again. If this isn't causing a problem I wouldn't do this.

Comment: The browser wasn't handing over the data to my javascript until the 1s was up. While looking into what value to set `keepalive_disable` to I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010346/force-nginx-to-close-the-connection-instantly) which seems to work. My site is an Angular website hitting an API so I'd only be sending requests as fast as a user can go so I'm not worried about disabling keepalive right now.

Comment: I guess keepalive_disable and keepalive_timeout of 0 are probably pretty similar. I'd do some performance testing before/after implementing this.